# Help with solving linear differential equations using an integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve this equation for $x=1$ using an integrating factor however for some reason my answer keeps turning out different from the book

In part a) I'm asked to find out $y$ using Euler's method when $x = 0.2$, my answer is correct here as $y = 4.46$.

The following equation is the one I'm trying to solve for $x=1$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} - 4xy = e^{2x^2}$$

In using taking $-4x$ and turning into the  integrating factor I get

$$I(x) = e^{-2x^2}$$ 
Thus the equation becomes the following after multiplying through by the integrating factor
$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-2x^2}y) = 1$$
So in following that line of logic I integrate both sides and try to find the value of $c$ using my knowledge from part a) but I keep coming up with the wrong answer

The integrated version for clarity

$$e^{-2x^2}y = x + c$$

---

**Edit:** I am given the initial condition $y=4$, $x=0$. I keep getting an answer in the region of $36$. My book is getting an answer of $x=1$, $y=4.55$.

Comment: What is the Initial Condition here?

Comment: initial condition $y =4$,  $x=0$

Comment: What is the answer at $x=1$ according to your book?

Comment: Hmmm... $y(0)=4$ hence $c=$ $__$ and $y(1)=e^2(1+c)=$ $___$. Where is the problem?

Comment: @R.Singh at x = 1 y = 4.55 in my book

Comment: @Did I dont understand what you're trying to say, you have empty boxes after your equals signs

Comment: Sorry but I am not "trying" to say anything, rather I am **telling** you how to completely solve your question, if only you have the slightest idea of what you wrote actually means. *Simply - fill - the -boxes*.

Comment: *"For some reason my answer keeps turning out different from the book"*. What answer are you getting?

Comment: Re the suggestion you say you found in your book, note that if $y'(x)=e^{2x^2}+4xy(x)$ and $y(0)\geqslant0$ then $y'(x)\geqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant0$, thus, $y(x)\geqslant y(0)+x$ for every $x\geqslant0$ hence, if $y(0)=4$ then $y(1)\geqslant5$, and the condition that $y(1)=4.55$ is absurd.

Comment: @projectilemotion i keep getting something in the region of 36

Comment: I am getting a similar answer to yours: $y(1)=5e^2\approx 36.945$. Your book is probably incorrect.

Comment: @Did I gathered that's what you were steering me to do but i've already tried to calculate the relevant variables using those steps but it keeps resulting in the wrong answer

Comment: Hence: **typo** (either in your book or in your transcription of your book).

Comment: @Adrian I added the information you provided in the comments to your post, so that we can clean the comments. Is that ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book's solution of $y(1)=4.55$ is certainly incorrect.

---

Based on the initial condition $y(0)=4$, one can evaluate the value of $c$. We have:
$$e^{-2x}y=x+c$$
$$e^{0}\cdot 4=0+c$$
$$c=4$$
Therefore, we can deduce that the solution satisfying the initial condition is:
$$y=xe^{2x}+4e^{2x}$$
Thus, the value of $y$ at $x=1$ should be:
$$y(1)=1e^{2}+4e^{2}=5e^2\approx 36.94528049$$
Since you seem to be getting something "In the region of $36$", this is similar, if not exactly what you obtained.